# WorkFront (AtTask) API: How to retrieve filters mentioned for Report

Tags: attask, workfront-api

We are using this url to get the report related information:
https://.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api-internal/v6.0/report/search?name=
&fields=*

Is it possible to get the filters mentioned on reports from WorkFront API?

I'm just seeing filter metadata not the actual filters used or values used:
https://.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api-internal/v6.0/filter/search?ID=58ec178c0075a140d3dc9ef7ff2b7cf4
&fields=*

So, can we get the output/details of report or can we get filters mentioned on report so if we change the filters we should be able to read them and get latest data of it.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very good question. You are able to access the filter object by its UUID (the field on the report is called filterID). However, you cannot actually look inside the object to see what components are a part of the filter.

Comment: Thanks for the info Brian!

Answer (score 0):

Try with specifying the `definition` field.

```
/attask/api-internal/v6.0/filter/search?ID=58ec178c0075a140d3dc9ef7ff2b7cf4 &fields=*,definition
```